# Book about a one-way time portal into the age of dinosaurs

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel, dinosaurs

I remember once having seen a book about the discovery/invention of a time travel portal into the age of dinosaurs.

The caveat: it is a one-way portal. You cannot return. The portal attracts adventurers and social dropouts.

It's been a fantasy sci-fi book, and that's all I remember.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you see/read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the main character/s of the book, such as age, sex, or occupation?

Comment: Are you certain it was the dinosaur age, as opposed to some other prehistoric time? Julian May's [Saga of Pliocene Exile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saga_of_Pliocene_Exile) had a similar premise but the one-way portal led to the Pliocene Epoch which was part of the Cenozoic (the 'age of mammals'). Short summary of the premise [here](https://sciencefiction.com/2011/10/22/lesser-known-science-fiction-novels-the-saga-of-pliocene-exile/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, this is almost certainly Julian May's Saga of the Exiles.

[Saga of the Exiles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saga_of_Pliocene_Exile)

Groups of social misfits, adventurers and certain types of criminals choose to leave the future society they do not conform to in order to journey through a one way portal six million years into the past.

The main plot follows six exiles in 'Group Green', that include a telepath who lost her abilities, an irresponsible and irrepressible joker, an anti-alien(racist) starship captain, an athlete who broke someone's arm in response to a sexual pass, a paleontologist who's wife has died and a 'Viking' with a traumatic childhood memory of being accidentally responsible for his mother's death.

The portal itself is the discovery of a french inventor and is geographically limited. It can only work in a certain region of France.

They journey into the past and discover a medieval society dominated by two related alien races who use their psychic powers to fight continuous battles and ritualised wars against each other.